# Laravel CSRF across subdomains, AJAX JS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, csrf

I seem to have an issue with CSRF protection when making a request from subdomain to my domain. I've set up CORS, but preflight check fails.

I've set up in my main head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And attached to each ajax request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

My CORS setup:

```
return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $allowedUrl)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-csrf-token');
```

Request fails:

> Failed to load https://example.com/account/login-ajax: Response to preflight 
>       request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
>       is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://sub.example.com' is therefore 
>       not allowed access.

Comment: Try moving your middleware to the global middleware if not already there. If it works then chances are the middleware is not running on `OPTIONS` requests.

Comment: It is already under global middleware. How could it not be running under `OPTIONS` if I listed it under methods?

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: What exactly? Global middleware in `Kernel` and `OPTIONS` under `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header

Comment: Here's the thing though. In any CORS request the browser sends an `OPTIONS` (pre-flight) request to the server. The server then needs to respond with the appropriate headers stating which origins, methods and headers are allowed. The browser then sends the normal  get or post or whatever request and expects the same access control headers to be sent back. In your case the browser said that the `OPTIONS` (pre-flight) request it sent did not have the correct access control headers in the response, which is consistent with your middleware not running and not putting those headers there.

Comment: I noticed that middleware doesn't even get triggered unless I remove the `x-csrf-token` from JS file. How can I "catch" the preflight request if it doesn't pass through it?

Comment: Actually no, sorry...that was happening when I removed it from global middleware